# При запуске решения, размещённого на сетевом диске, в Visual Studio 2019 выходит ошибка DEP0700: Не удалось зарегистрировать приложение. [0x80073D1F]

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Windows 10. Системный диск маленький. При установке проектов любых шаблонов на нём (C:) всё работает. Но поскольку места мало предпочитаю работать с проектами на сетевом диске. При этом:

При создании проектов C# для рабочего стола на основе шаблона **Пустое приложение (универсальное приложение для Windows)** или **Windows Template Studio (Universal Windows)** (похоже, всё что связано с **UWP**) при запуске возникает ошибка. В окне **Вывод** распечатывается следующий текст:

> Создание нового пустого макета... Копирование файлов: всего 7 МБ в
> макет... Проверка установки необходимых платформ... Регистрация
> приложения для запуска из макета... DEP0700: Не удалось
> зарегистрировать приложение. [0x80073D1F] Неопознанная ошибка
>
> ========== Развертывание: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, пропущено: 0 ==========

Но если создать проект C# на основе шаблона **Консольное приложение (.NET Core)**, или на основе **WPF**, или **Windows Forms**)), то оно работает без проблем на этом же сетевом диске.

Создаётся впечатление, что не хватает прав доступа. Но это лишь моё предположение.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как справиться с проблемой.

**P.S.** Нечто подобное происходит с проектом на основе шаблона **Веб-приложение ASP.NET (.NET Framework)**. Ошибка:

> Отказано в доступе. Описание: При доступе к ресурсам, которые
> требуются для обслуживания данного запроса, возникла ошибка. Возможно,
> Вы не обладаете правом просмотра запрошенных ресурсов. Сообщение об
> ошибке 401.3: Указанные вами учётные данные не дают прав на просмотр
> этого каталога или страницы (отказ в доступе согласно спискам контроля
> доступа). Обратитесь к администратору веб-сервера за разрешением
> доступа к 'Здесь указан путь...'

При этом проект на основе шаблона **Веб-приложение ASP.NET Core** работает отлично и там и там...

Comment: Создайте проект на C:, закройте студию и просто скопируйте весь каталог с проектом туда, куда надо.

Comment: @aepot , трюк с копированием не прошёл, к сожалению. Первоначально в сообщении некоторые шаблоны ошибочно были указаны как подверженные проблеме, но при экспериментах с ними выяснилось, что они работают нормально и на сетевом диске. Так вот их, действительно можно переместить, как вы советовали, но это не имеет смысла, т.к. они и так работают на сетевом диске при первичном размещении их там. Прошу прощение за неточную информацию в первоначальном вопросе.